# R data.table merge drops rows (December only)

Tags: r, data.table

Solved with the help of @Uwe Block.

R data.table merge drops December observations by shifting the month-index back in one data set while trying to merge a monthly data set onto a set of daily observations. What's a good way to do this merge that works as expected?

Using merge per @Harry Daniels `merge(monthly, daily, by=c("year","month"), all=TRUE)` instead of  `daily[monthly, on=c("year","month"), all=TRUE]` retains all daily observations correctly, but the monthly data are still shifted so that January->0.

Problem: generating the month and year columns on the monthly dataset made months not quite exactly integer values. I.e. 1 was actually 0.999999999999091 so the merge took the floor internally and offset it.
Example: `monthly[,month:=100*(Date%%1)]' where the date was stored as numeric 2016.01, 2016.02,...,2016.12.

See the following:

```
> monthly
    year month     CPI
 1: 2016     1 236.916
 2: 2016     2 237.111
 3: 2016     3 238.132
 4: 2016     4 239.261
 5: 2016     5 240.229
 6: 2016     6 241.018
 7: 2016     7 240.628
 8: 2016     8 240.849
 9: 2016     9 241.428
10: 2016    10 241.729
11: 2016    11 241.353
12: 2016    12 241.432

> daily
           date year month   close
  1: 2016-01-04 2016     1 2012.66
  2: 2016-01-05 2016     1 2016.71
  3: 2016-01-06 2016     1 1990.26
  4: 2016-01-07 2016     1 1943.09
  5: 2016-01-08 2016     1 1922.03
 ---                              
248: 2016-12-23 2016    12 2263.79
249: 2016-12-27 2016    12 2268.88
250: 2016-12-28 2016    12 2249.92
251: 2016-12-29 2016    12 2249.26
252: 2016-12-30 2016    12 2238.83

> daily[monthly, on=c("year","month")]
           date year month   close     CPI
  1:       <NA> 2016     0      NA 236.916
  2: 2016-01-04 2016     1 2012.66 237.111
  3: 2016-01-05 2016     1 2016.71 237.111
  4: 2016-01-06 2016     1 1990.26 237.111
  5: 2016-01-07 2016     1 1943.09 237.111
 ---                                      
228: 2016-11-23 2016    11 2204.72 241.432
229: 2016-11-25 2016    11 2213.35 241.432
230: 2016-11-28 2016    11 2201.72 241.432
231: 2016-11-29 2016    11 2204.66 241.432
232: 2016-11-30 2016    11 2198.81 241.432

> merge(monthly, daily, by=c("year","month"), all=TRUE)
     year month     CPI   close
  1: 2016     0 236.916      NA
  2: 2016     1 237.111 2012.66
  3: 2016     1 237.111 2016.71
  4: 2016     1 237.111 1990.26
  5: 2016     1 237.111 1943.09
 ---                           
249: 2016    12      NA 2263.79
250: 2016    12      NA 2268.88
251: 2016    12      NA 2249.92
252: 2016    12      NA 2249.26
253: 2016    12      NA 2238.83
```

Comment: Using a dataframe to index another dataframe doesn't seem like a good idea.

Your best bet is the `merge()` function.  You can use `by = 'month'` to specify which column(s) you want to merge on, and `all.x = T` or `all.y = T` to recreate outer joins in SQL.

Comment: I think you want `daily[monthly, on=c("year", "month")]`.

Comment: @Balter In data.tables, `x[i]` is a left join (... I think that's what it's called). The "index" notation is used since it looks up each row of `i` in `x`, similar to how `X[Y]` works with matrices.

Comment: @Imo right you are. I had it with the year and month columns set as keys so it ran through. I had cleared by workspace before running it again but setkey was still executed. Same problem though.

Comment: Please, [edit] your question and add the output of `dput(daily)` and `dput(monthly)`. This will help to reproduce the problem and to see what data types are in your data. Thank you.

Comment: @Uwe Block will do. On a similar vein just realized month/years were int in one table and num in the other. Fixed it and no difference.

Comment: @Uwe Block see full code with dputs at https://pastebin.com/NcYE1xag

Comment: @Uwe Block I was just looking at str, not dput. Thanks for the tip, see the solution in question.

Answer (score 0):

This should suffice:

```
merge(monthly, daily , by = 'month', all = TRUE )
```

Comment: If you merge only by month, what will happen if there are data of more than one year, e.g. 2016 *and* 2017?

Comment: @Harry Daniels and @Uwe Block Using the merge function results in a complete data.set but the monthly data is still offset by a month, so that January is in month '0'.  
    
`merge(monthly, daily, by=c("year","month"), all=TRUE)`